# Window Forms Split Container Border Width

Tags: c#, forms, containers

Now this *should* be a simple task, but I just can't wrap my head around it. I've got a split container in my windows forms but there's no way for me to change the border between the panels. In the preview window:

[image: Preview]

However once compiled, it only appears this length:

[image: Compiled]

I've tried changing the margin sizes, as well as the splitter-width property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both of your images are identical...

Comment: Should be updated, thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this property is not altered anywhere in code?

Comment: The only mention of these containers elsewhere in the code are the Paint functions: https://snag.gy/4u0GYy.jpg

Comment: `SplitterWidth` is the correct `property`. Perhaps you initalialize the `SplitContainer` somewhere in the code again, which overrides the configured values?